# Specify sql variable in dbt

Tags: dbt

I want to specify this select statement in my dbt model:

`select @rowcount from <xxx table>`

Where the `@rowcount` variable defines as int. Can any one suggest me to represent this in DBT?

Comment: Which database are you using with dbt? Some SQL dialects support this directly (postgres) while others don't

Answer (score 1):

If this is in SQL Server, isn't the syntax `@@RowCount`?

Pre-supposing that, there are two in development `dbt` "Adapter" projects to SQL Server:

Per the docs on [supported dbs](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/supported-databases/):

- [dbt-sqlserver](https://github.com/mikaelene/dbt-sqlserver) - SQL Server 2016 and later
- [dbt-mssql](https://github.com/jacobm001/dbt-mssql) -  SQL Server 2008 R2 and later

Depending on your version, I would recommend opening an issue for that particular variable if it doesn't work as-is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a window functions depending on your SQL dialect!

Big Query || Snowflake || SQLServer || AWS:

```
SELECT row_number() over () as row_count, *
from <xxx table>
```